# How to compare the next value in a array c#

Tags: c#

process involves adding toppings to individual pudding that have varying sizes that roll out on a conveyor belt.

1. At least 1g of toppings needs to be added to each pudding.
2. If two adjacent puddings are of different sizes, the larger piece needs to have at least 1g more than the smaller one.
3. If two adjacent pieces are of the same size, then the amount of toppings relative to each other does not matter.

XXXXXXX

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //topping t1 = new topping();
        //t1.CalTopping();

        topping t1 = new topping();
        t1.CalTopping();
    }

    public class topping
    {
     

        public void CalTopping()
        {
            int[] cupcakes = { 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1 };
            int tot = 0;
            int topping = 0;
            //int i=0;



            for (int i = 0; i < cupcakes.Length; i++)
            {
                
                if (i + 1 < cupcakes.Length)
                {
                    topping = 1;
                    if (cupcakes[i] == cupcakes[0])
                    {
                        topping = 1;
                    }

                    else if (cupcakes[i] > cupcakes[i - 1])
                    {

                        topping = topping + 1;
                    }
                    else
                        topping = 1;
                }

                tot = tot + topping;
                Console.WriteLine(cupcakes[i] + " = " + topping + "g");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("total toppings Amount:-" + tot + "g");

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried? Think about keeping track of the previous item and using that and the current item in a loop.

Comment: You are using a foreach loop, `i` is not an index.

Comment: I don't see how rule (2) can work if the puddings come out on a conveyor belt. If ten puddings come out in order from large to small, the first pudding will need +9 on its toppings... but you won't know that until you reach the end of the conveyor belt. Are you allowed to run it multiple times?

Comment: only one pudding comes out of the conveyor belt at a time but when the topping is applied it checks with the next pudding which is the big

Comment: I agree with John Wu… requirement #2 sounds odd in a conveyor system and #3 appears meaningless/irrelevant. I do not see how you can do this without at least two passes through the array/conveyor. However, it appears there is no MAX toppings requirement. So a simple solution may be to simply add the same number of toppings as the size… 1=1, 2=2 and 6=6. This would fulfill all three (3) requirements. I suspect there are other requirements you are not telling us.

Comment: As John Wu said, lets say you have 5 puddigs of sizes 5,4,3,2,1. Since first > second, we put 3g topping on it. Then we need to put 2g to second (it is smaller), 1g to third (it is also smaller), and 0g to fourth, which conflicts with requirement 1. Either you have to start with a topping amount larger than total item count, or you just apply toppings with the same size of the pudding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm to fulfill the requirements:

1. The first cupcake gets 1g of topping
2. If the current cupcake is larger than the previous, it get 1g more topping of the previous, otherwise it gets 1g of topping.
3. Repeat step 2 for all cupcakes.

Processing sequential pairs can be done with a loop like

```
for (int i = 1; i < cupcakes.Length; i++) { 
    var current = cupcakes[i];
    var previous = cupcakes[i-1];
    ...
```

Now, the question specified *adjacent* and not *subsequent*. To handle this we also need to do a loop in the reverse order using the same logic, but in this pass we need to take the maximum of the currently assigned topping amount and the new amount.

For example, Cupcakes of size `1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1` would get toppings of size

1. forward pass: `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1`
2. reverse pass: `1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1`,
3. maximum of both: `1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1`.

This would not fit very well in the conveyor belt analogy since it would require the belt to go backwards and forwards, and require all cupcakes to be placed on the belt. But there are real world applications for algorithms like this.

Comment: An Exception is throne "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' if i use this  var previous = cupcakes[i-1];
"

Comment: @PereraX If an exception is thrown it is probably due to an issue with the *implementation*. Part of development is reading exceptions, trying to understand what they mean, and how to fix the implementation, a debugger will help with this. Luckily, most .net exceptions tell you what the problem is fairly well.

Comment: @PereraX If `cupcakes[i-1]` throws, what is `i`? Is that value reasonable? Why does it have that value? What do you think it should have as a value?